# Space movie seen on pogo tv with a man in a malfunctioning space pod

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

In my childhood, a space movie probably used to come on Pogo TV in which a man's pod malfunctioned and opens early and he eats alone some paste tube food for many days. And when the other persons wake up, they saw he has made a painting from the food on the roof of the spaceship.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know how old you are, so approximately what year would you have seen this?

Comment: Was the man still alive when the others woke up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Painting on the roof with food shows up in the 1997 Disney movie [*RocketMan*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120029/).  Per [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/RocketMan1997):

> When the crew is put to hypersleep to shorten the journey, a chimp named Ulysses switches pods with the reluctant Fred, **disrupting his sleep months earlier** than everyone else during the journey.
>
> With the crew asleep, Fred has no choice but to amuse himself with data studies of Mars and **creating a Sistine Chapel-style painting on the ceiling** with the supplies provided.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RocketMan_(1997_film)) confirms Fred being awake for the trip and painting with food:

> Fred, along with Commander Overbeck, geologist Julie Ford, and Ulysses, a trained chimpanzee, will look for fossils on Mars. To save on resources, crew members are put into "hypersleep" for eight months while the ship floats towards Mars. Ulysses purposely takes Fred's "hypersleep chamber" for his own and Fred has to sleep in Ulysses' chimp-sized chamber. **He sleeps for only 13 minutes and has to stay up alone for eight months.**
>
> [...]
>
> The crew makes it to Mars, after Overbeck tells off Fred for being awake the whole time and **using all the food**—except food that the former despises: (anchovy paste, creamed liver, and gefilte fish)—**for painting**.

Comment: I think it is correct....This question used to come to my mind again and again but due to not getting the answer, I used to leave it disappointed. Thank you so so much DavidW for solving my problem